# Select rows where column value appears multiple times while grouped on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having-clause

I'd like to group by two columns, `ClientID, TypeID`, and select all the rows where `ClientID` values have more than one occurences in the table. So not just the list of these values but all the rows instead.

For example, this my inner subquery result:

```
╔══════════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ ClientID ║ TypeID ║ Count(*) ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "0"      ║ "1"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "455"    ║ "1"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "455"    ║ "2"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "455"    ║ "8"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "40036"  ║ "8"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "40070"  ║ "7"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "40070"  ║ "8"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "40082"  ║ "2"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "40082"  ║ "12"   ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "40085"  ║ "1"    ║ "1"      ║
╚══════════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

And I'd want this output:

```
╔══════════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ ClientID ║ TypeID ║ Count(*) ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "455"    ║ "1"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "455"    ║ "2"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "455"    ║ "8"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "40070"  ║ "7"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "40070"  ║ "8"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "40082"  ║ "2"    ║ "1"      ║
╠══════════╬════════╬══════════╣
║ "40082"  ║ "12"   ║ "1"      ║
╚══════════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

As you can see it is exactly the same, only the rows where the ClientID value does not appear more than once are gone.

This is my MySQL query, however this gives me an empty result naturally, since all the rows are unique so the `Count(*)` column will never be above 1, not like with grouping by a single field instead of two in this case.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS C
FROM (
    SELECT ClientID, TypeID
    FROM table
    GROUP BY ClientID, TypeID
) AS R
GROUP BY ClientID, TypeID
HAVING COUNT(C) > 1
ORDER BY ClientID, TypeID
```

How should I count the groups where both columns are being aggregated, so the `Count(*)` field would actually hold the proper number of the occurences?

Comment: If you are grouping, that should happen automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exists` and `distinct`:

```
select distinct clientID, typeID
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.clientID = t.clientID and t1.typeID <> t.typeID
)
```

Or if you want the count as well, use aggregation instead of `distinct`:

```
select clientID, typeID, count(*) cnt
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.clientID = t.clientID and t1.typeID <> t.typeID
)
group by clientID, typeID
```

For performance, consider an index on `(clientID, typeID)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select t.*,
(select count(*)from table i where i.ClientID=t.ClientID and i.TypeID=t.TypeID) as Count 
from table t where clientID in (
select ClientID from table
GROUP BY ClientID
HAVING COUNT(ClientID) > 1)
```